# measuring wireless (inductive) power supplies

Tags: wireless, measurement, induction, inductive, wireless-charging

I bought an electric toothbrush with a lithium-ion battery and wireless (inductive) charger. It came with one of those air/water jet flossing accessories, which also has a lithium-ion battery and a separate wireless (inductive) charger.

I noticed both devices are compatible with both chargers, despite the instruction manual indicating otherwise. I suppose they have different specifications. Also, not surprisingly I found a different brand toothbrush  also worked with both chargers and vice versa (Philips vs Braun).

I assume mixing and matching could effect battery life and so on where the specifications aren't exactly optimal. Is there some method to determine or predict the effect/consequences of doing this; and how might I (wirelessly?) measure the properties (i.e., output - Volts, Amps, Watts, Joules, Ohms, Hertz, continuity etc.) of an inductive charger and corresponding internal battery/receiver? Usually I would just use a traditional multimeter by probing the exposed (i.e., non-wireless) terminals.

Note: Consistent with the emerging paradigm of consumer electronics; the devices actually appear to be sealed and designed so the battery can't be replaced or even accessed. At least not non-destructively, or without considerable difficulty.

My motivation for asking the question is not anything to do with any of the specific products I've mentioned (I don't really care about toothbrushes, etc. they're just a nice example and useful segue), but more an intellectual curiosity regarding electronics and engineering in general.

Comment: I'd create a coil of wire which will fit in the charger, connect a 1kΩ wirewound resistor across it's leads, and measure what happens on a 'scope. Knowing the number of turns, resistance, and measured voltage, one could at least estimate the power delivered and see at what frequency.

Comment: @rdtsc okay, interesting. So dismantle charger/cradle thing and position a small 1kΩ coil of wire where exactly? Is it soldered to anything or just floating around in close proximity? When you say *the leads*, you mean the ends of the coil, or something else? (I haven't opened one up yet, I'm not even really sure what I expect it to look like.)

Comment: I'm assuming the cordless toothbrush has a round base, and sits on a charging cradle. So make the coil of wire in the shape of the toothbrush base and place it onto the charger.  So that the coil of wire is acting as the "pickup" instead of the toothbrush. All pieces are likely ultrasonically-welded and/or glued; disassembling it would likely be a one-way process.